# What makes that volatile breaks pointer-arithmetic with structs?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

In our code we use pointers to structures to deduct addresses of hardware registers to keep the code readable.

For example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct reg {
    uint32_t t;
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t value;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct reg *r = reinterpret_cast<struct reg *>(0x800000);

    std::cerr << &r->value << "\n";
    std::cerr << &r->t << "\n";
    std::cerr << &r->x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The hardware-base-address is 0x800000 and using `writeReg(&t->x, 123);` will make it write to 0x800004.

By accident a `volatile`-keyword was wrongly placed in the structure-definition:

```
struct reg {
    volatile uint32_t t;
    volatile uint32_t x;
    volatile uint32_t value;
};
```

What happened now is that all fields have the offset 1 using the `&r->field`-syntax.

Using `g++ (Debian 9.2.1-4) 9.2.1 20190821` here.

Rewriting the test in C using printf and a C-style-cast gives again the correct offset even with volatile.

I'm unable to unable to understand why the volatile-keyword seems to break pointer-arithmetic? Why is that so? What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no overload of `operator<<` for printing pointers to `volatile`.

The best suitable overload your compiler finds is the one for printing `bool`, so your pointers get converted to `bool`.

Try:

```
std::cerr << (void *)&r->value << "\n";
```

Comment: Wait, does this work? Don't you need a `const_cast` too?

Comment: @Brian Oops, it doesn't. Edited.